# Mozilla CSS bug : table with bottom-border + border-collapse : causes random borders to appear and disappear

Tags: firefox, border

When applying a bottom border to a table, with `border-collapse` set to "collapse", weird random bottom borders appear below some table rows, of varying widths -- they appear and disappear when scrolling, sort of like the IE6 "peekaboo bug"; resizing the window, or switching to another application and back again, makes them go away, scrolling makes them reappear again.

This affects all Mozilla browsers (Mac & PC) including Firefox, Camino, and Flock -- and only mozilla browsers.

Example:

http://platypusman.com/mozilla_table_border-bottom_border-collapse.html

The CSS:

```
table.grid { border-collapse: collapse; border-bottom: solid 15px #ccc; }
table.grid td { border: solid 1px #ccc; padding: 5px; }
```

Removing "border-collapse" fixes the issue.

It's only caused by a BOTTOM border on the table -- removing the bottom border fixes the issue. E.g.:

```
table.grid { border-collapse: collapse; border: solid 15px #ccc; border-bottom: none; }
table.grid td { border: solid 1px #ccc; padding: 5px; }
```

Comment: Its interesting that i havent seen this before now on something ive done...

Comment: You should file a bug at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org if you haven't already.

Comment: Looks like this is fixed in development -- I was going to report the bug but first downloaded the latest build (3.7) and the problem is gone in this version.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed, probably by the [border collapsing rewrite](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=452319), which will be included in the next major Firefox version after 3.6.